# Writing a short command in Python that compiles and executes 32-bit Assembly code

Tags: python, linux, assembly

Currently I am using NASM as my main compiler and Geany as the program I am writing my code. I am using linux mint so that is why I am not using MASM.

I figured to import os and try to run the commands from there. This is what my code looks like so far:

```
# This program compiles and runs ASM code in the terminal

import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    program_name = raw_input("Enter program name: ")
    one = "cd"
    two = "cd /home/daniel/Desktop/CS3b"
    three = "nasm -f elf "+program_name+".asm"
    four = "ld -m elf_i386 -s -o "+program_name+" "+program_name+".o"
    five = "./"+program_name
    os.system(one)
    os.system(two)
    os.system(three)
    os.system(four)
    os.system(five)
```

When I hand-type the code into the terminal, it compiles and executes perfectly. However, when I run this command in the terminal, I get this error message.

```
/home/daniel/Desktop/CS3b/compiler.py: 2: /home/daniel/Desktop/CS3b/compiler.py:: not found
```

And when I try to run the compuler as a .pyc file, nothing happens (or seems that nothing happens).

Comment: What is the command you are using to run this file?

Comment: Perhaps shell script is the better language for this particular task?

Comment: You are executing shell commands, so every command runs in it's own shell session. This is why your initial `cd` command doesn't change the working directory for the rest of your commands. (try running `pwd && <your_command>` to see).

Comment: @nneonneo I am not very versed in shell so I don't know how I would code that

Comment: @Daniel it's a great time to learn ;-P You practically are doing most of the shell work already, but have added extra stuff to make your Python script work.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Do you have any good resources that you found helpful in learning shell?

Comment: use `os.system(";".join([one,two,three,four,five]))` rather than typing all commands seperately

Comment: Here's a good comprehensive guide for Bash: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/  Depending on your needs, you may be able to come up with a 1 liner like: `nasm -f elf *.asm && ld -m elf_i386 -s *.o -o out && ./out` If any part of this chained command fails, it will stop and report what failed. If it succeeds, it will continue onto the next part of the chained command (separated by the `&&`).

Comment: @Daniel Here is a quick and dirty Bash script to do the same process your python code does: http://pastebin.com/kUSzKAuK  Put it in a file, such as `compile_and_run.sh` and execute it like `./compile_and_run.sh <program_name>`

Comment: @SnakeDoc Thanks for the code! I tried running it in the terminal but I get the error `No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Daniel the above code assumes you are in the directory with the source files. Otherwise, you could specify the full path, like `./compile_and_run.sh /home/daniel/Desktop/CS3b/<program_name>`, but this may get confused when it's outputting to disk. If you need it to switch directories, add something like your `cd /home/daniel/Desktop/CS3b/` before the first `nasm` command.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Thanks! I'll add that to my code.